# Default form size for WTForms

Tags: wtforms, flask-wtforms

I want to have the long form which is at least size = 50, and in the html i have:

```
{{ form.name(size=50) }}
```

However, I have like 10 forms for each page, is it any way that I can ignore this redundant way and work around? (without having size=50)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to accomplish that, depending on where in your chain you want to tackle it. But I would think the templating layer is where you should solve this, since what you want is pure presentation.

Assuming you are using Jinja2, you could write a small macro that presets the `size` keyword argument of each field you wish to render:

Macro:

```
{% macro render_field(field) -%}
    {% if field.type != 'HiddenField' %}
        <label for="{{ field.id }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
       {{ field(size=50, **kwargs) }}
    {% endif %}
{%- endmacro %}
```

Notice in the field call I preset its `size` to `50`.

Next, to render the field, you simply call this macro with the field name (`some_field` in this case):

```
{{ render_field(form.some_field) }}
```

This is assuming you put the macro and the field render code in the same template file.
For larger templates, it is recommended to split your macros and render code into different files. Macros go in "_helper" files as per convention.

If you put this macro in a file called "form_helper.html", for example, you need to first import this file into the template which contains your actual field rendering code:

```
{% import 'form_helper.html' as form_helper %}
```

Now all your macros residing in `form_helper.html` are available in the `form_helper` namespace. Your field rendering code would thus become:

```
{{ form_helper.render_field(form.some_field) }}
```

Comment: Could you please remove the `-` character in the statement to close the `macro` block?

Comment: @Gianluca Maybe unusual but as far as I am aware this is the official syntax to close a macro in Jinja2.